# How to create a 'only' button for a checkbox menu?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a button 'only' for a checkbox menu that would uncheck everything (within each menu) except the closest checkbox.
[image]

I have some code that works, but it's a sort of hack and instead I would like to say in 1 line something like:

- *if* $(this).closest('.checkbox').find('input') *is* `checked` *then uncheck, else leave as is*

Also, I need the event to be fired as the user actually clicked (is it with `triggerHandler`)?

```js
$('.only').on('click', function() {

   $(this).closest('.checkbox').find('input').prop('checked', false);
   $(this).closest('.row').find('input').prop('checked', true);
   $(this).closest('.checkbox').find('input').prop('checked', false);
   $(this).closest('.row').find('input').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
.only {
  border: 1px solid rgb(115, 135, 156);
  float: right;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  padding-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="right">
                        <div class="only">only</div>
                      </div>
                    <label>
                        <input name="countryOriginMenu" value="Not provided" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
                         <span>Frist</span>
                     </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="right">
                        <div class="only">only</div>
                      </div>
                    <label>
                        <input name="countryOriginMenu" value="Not provided" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
                         <span>Second</span>
                     </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="right">
                        <div class="only">only</div>
                      </div>
                    <label>
                        <input name="countryOriginMenu" value="Not provided" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
                         <span>Third</span>
                     </label>
                    </div>
                  
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2m0cu795/:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trigger the wrong event, use change  Remove a duplicate line.
NOTE: IF you trigger the "click" it changes the value while "change" does not.

```
$('.only').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.checkbox').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
  $(this).closest('.row').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
});
```

Alternately, you can NOT change the current ones value, whatever its value (the ONLY) one with:

```
$('.only').on('click', function() {
  var cb = $(this).closest('.checkbox').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  var me = $(this).closest('.row').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  cb.not(me).prop('checked', false);
  me.trigger('change');
});
```

OR do the trigger on the OTHER checkboxes: (since they are the ones changing)

```
cb.not(me).prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

On click:

- Check the current one in case it isn't.
- Uncheck all except the current.

See this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4bjtuunr/5/

```
$('.only').on('click', function() {
    var $current = $(this).closest('.row').find('input');
    var $cbxs = $(this).closest('.checkbox').find('input');
    $current.prop('checked', true);
    $cbxs.not($current).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the OP, I need to select/deselect conditionally. One of the reasons is that I have a error message that triggers if no boxes are selected.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. Your example of the conditional says "if checked: uncheck, otherwise leave unchecked". Why do you need conditional, the result would be the same in that case?

Comment: Right, which is not what your (and my) solution is doing. I also specified I need to simulate a user click, since I have a dashboard where the checkbox is a filter and the recalculation is not triggered unless there is a click event.I am not familiar with JQuery but my understanding is that `prop('checked', true)` only changes the appearance of the button.

Comment: I see. When clicking "only", if the current one is unchecked, it should remain unchecked?

Also, you can listen to the change-event instead of trigger click event. Another option is to call a common callback function for both events.

Comment: Nope, the 'only' button should should keep/change to `checked` only the corresponding checkbox. And at no point in time I am allowed to have zero checkboxes selected.

Comment: My latest edition might work then. I didn't add the trigger('click'), but you can always do that if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

How about using this. This can help you maintain the current checkbox's state without too many conditions to check.

```
   var row = $(this).parents(".row");
   row.siblings().find('input').prop('checked', false);
   row.find('input').prop('checked', true);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ydzbddd5/4/

Comment: `$($(this).parents(".row")).siblings()` can simply be `$(this).parents(".row").siblings()` perhaps?

Comment: With your NEW line `var r= $(this).parents(".row"); r.siblings()` and `r.find(` avoids the double dom process

Comment: It's what this site is for :)  I like the siblings BTW